# How to get the value of csv text and insert into access

Tags: arrays, ms-access, delphi, tstringlist

I have a string like this from my memo1:

> model,"GHN-888",id,"00000000",date,"04-21-2016",type,1

how can I make it like this:

> Model = GHN-888
>   id = 00000000
>   date = 04/21/2016
>   type = 1

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parse the string and build your query. Although you should be using SQL  parameters.

Comment: So, are you intending to a) parse the original string, and b) serialize the data back into a differently formatted string? What does the second string have to do with "insert into access"?

Comment: And what does your question have to do with arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TStringList` to parse this line. Has a simple method for divide strings using the properties, `Delimiter`, `DelimitedText` and `StrictDelimiter`.

[See the help about this properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings_Properties).

You can use a code like this:

```
var
  TS:TStringList;
begin
  TS := TStringList.Create();
  TS.StrictDelimiter := True;
  TS.Delimiter := ',';
  TS.DelimitedText := 'model,"GHN-888",id,"00000000",date,"04-21-2016",type,1';
```

Now (after assigning the `DelimitedText` property) the `TStringList` has divided the text using the char `','`
And you have 8 lines with this values:

```
Model
GHN-888
id
00000000
date
04-21-2016
type
1
```

Now it is easy to obtain the values ​​individually, with a loop o using TS[0], TS[1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TStrings_Properties), TS[2]...

Comment: Do we really need yet another answer explaining how to split a string. Do a search. There are hundreds out there.